# Laravel Livewire: after any method call, my array gets nullified

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

So i have a livewire component that has two properties a `$viewedJob` and `$jobs` which is a collection of jobs that are related to `$viewedJob`. my logic is that. When you click on a job, that job becomes `$viewedJob` easy task.

so i set up a livewire method to do the logic

```php
public function viewJob($jobId) 
{
    $this->viewedJob = Job::find($jobId);
    $this->jobs = $this->jobs;
}
```

and inside my frontend i call it this way

```xml
<button wire:click="viewJob({{$job}})" class="truncate">
    {{$job->title}}
</button>
```

**MY PROBLEM**

the problem is that whenever the `viewJob` method gets called, the `$jobs` array gets nulliefied, each peoprty inside it will become null and i get this error

[image]

i tried also not doing anything inside `viewJob` and still get the same error

```php
public function viewJob($jobId) 
{
    // although i dont do anything, i still get the same error!!
}
```

any ideas will help, thank you for your time.

Comment: It would help if you show some more of your code, its pretty hard to debug, replicate the issue or pinpoint the issue with what you currently have - I am pretty sure its elsewhere in your code (related to some re-render or re-hydrate perhaps).. One thing, though - `$this->jobs = $this->jobs;` does nothing? Set jobs to itself?

Comment: Post the code that throws the error. The part where you try to show the owner property in your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your frontend code is in a loop of $jobs variable you should try this.

```
<button wire:click="viewJob({{$job->id}})" class="truncate">
    {{$job->title}}
</button>
```

if this not working you should make your $jobs collection into an array like:

```
$this->jobs = Job::all()->toArray();
```

and in frontend you can write like:

```
<button wire:click="viewJob({{$job['id']}})" class="truncate">
    {{$job['title']}}
</button>
```

I hope it will work. My answer is on based that your front end code is inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a loop, don't forget the `wire:key` element. It's solved a lot of issues by my side

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).